# Botium K-fold cross validation on DialogFlow throws precondition errors

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm trying to run k-fold cross validation of my DialogFlow model (as described [here](https://medium.com/@floriantreml/tutorial-benchmark-your-chatbot-on-watson-dialogflow-wit-ai-and-more-92885b4fbd48)) on Botium. These are the steps I followed:

- Extracted training content using `botium-cli nlpextract` from DialogFlow (around 600 utterances spread over 6 intents)
- Setup config files for Dialogflow and IBM Watson
- Ran a k-fold cross validation
  for both platforms (`botium-cli nlpanalytics k-fold`)
  While the validation ran fine on Watson, on Dialogflow a lot of errors came up for some fold runs while other fold runs ran fine . Example error below:

```
com.google.apps.framework.request.StatusException: <eye3 title='FAILED_PRECONDITION'/> 
generic::FAILED_PRECONDITION: Intent with id '******-****-d8298f23f5af' not found 
among intents in environment '' for agent with id '******-**-****-ab10e1f8c943'.
```

Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong in the DialogFlow tests? The precision and recall also came out very low for these runs as compared to Watson where almost all test results were > 0.9

My Dialogflow config looks like this:

```
{
  "botium": {
    "Capabilities": {
      "PROJECTNAME": "agentblr",
      "CONTAINERMODE": "dialogflow",
      "DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID": "<project id>",
      "DIALOGFLOW_CLIENT_EMAIL": "<service access email>",
      "DIALOGFLOW_PRIVATE_KEY": "<service access key>",
      "DIALOGFLOW_NLP_PROJECT_ID":  "<empty test project>",
      "DIALOGFLOW_NLP_CLIENT_EMAIL": "<empty test project service access email>",
      "DIALOGFLOW_NLP_PRIVATE_KEY": "<empty test project service access key>",
      "DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE":  "en"
            
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Dialogflow environments ? If yes you have to tell Botium with capabilitiy DIALOGFLOW_ENVIRONMENT

Comment: Nope. I haven't set any environment on DialogFlow. Do I need to set one for this script to work?